# Change iOS simulator name in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm debugging two programs in Flutter ios, but in VS Code the simulator name appears the same for the two devices, how can I rename the devices to differentiate when I launch the app?
I have tried change the name in Hardware/device/manage Devices menu, but it doesn't works.
[image]